# Having trouble working out how two vector expressions are equivalent

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, linear-regression

I'm doing some coursework on linear regression, and part of it requires finding a closed-form solution of the mean-squared error minimisation problem:

$$\min_{\bf w} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x}_i - y_i)^2$$

This is how I tried to do it (with some help from online sources):

$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \nabla_{\bf{w}} (\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x}_i - y_i)^2 = 0 \\
\Rightarrow \frac{2}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}(\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x}_i - y_i) \mathbf{x}_i = 0 \\
\Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{n}(\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x}_i) \mathbf{x}_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i \mathbf{x}_i \\
\Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbf{x}_i \mathbf{x}_i^T \mathbf{w} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i \mathbf{x}_i
$$

My only issue here is rearranging the left-hand side to get from the second-last to the last line. Could someone show me how this is done? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $\mathbf{a}_{i} := (\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x}_i)$ are scalars and so $\mathbf{a}_{i} = \mathbf{a}_{i}^T = (\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x}_i)^T = (\mathbf{x}_i^T \mathbf{w})$. By virtue of being scalars they also commute with the vectors, $\mathbf{x}_i$, giving us $$\mathbf{a}_{i} \mathbf{x}_i = \mathbf{a}_{i}^T \mathbf{x}_i = \mathbf{x}_i \mathbf{a}_{i}^T.$$ Hence $$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i \mathbf{x}_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x}_i) \mathbf{x}_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbf{x}_i \mathbf{x}_i^T \mathbf{w}.$$